# Google play console not showing app statistics nor show up when i search it in playstore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I have already published few app on Google Play, and they showed after hour or 2 on google play store when i searched for same words. But it has been 25 hours i published my app which also got 100+ download because of reddit but its not showing up when i search the exact same words.

And also google play Console (both in app and on website) is not updating the data/statistics about the app except in app which only shows 197 download but not other.

And here is what i did different from my other app, this time i choose target audience adults and also 9+ which comes under the children section and i did provide privacy policy for it.

Any clues why the statistics/data is not updating or why the app is not showing when searching on Google Play Store?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Expect at least 2 weeks before your new app is listed in the rankings.
Then it depends where the algorithms placed your app.

You get no statistics because nobody is able to find your app in the play store.

Comment: so, today is 3rd day, and I'm able to see the data now but not the app in the search result. So I will wait.

Comment: @TehleelMir so how long did you wait for it to show

Comment: @Brightcode I don't remember this time how long it took, I think one or two weeks maybe, but yeah it showed up. So wait a little it will show up :)